# Which job runs on which node?

Tags: perl, awk, slurm

Here is a quick question that often comes up and challenges my AWK skills. How do I list all jobs on a cluster together with a list of nodes they are allocated.

Something like:

```
 JobId          Job Name    State      Hosts
               . . .
 29428   _2.0_cont_7.job        R      fm3/6
 29429   _2.2_cont_7.job        R      fm3/6
 29430   _2.4_cont_8.job        R      fm1/6
 29431   _2.6_cont_8.job        R      fm1/6
 29835           taverna        R   mathserv/40
               . . .
```

Is there a parameter to `sinfo` or `qstat` that would provide a similar output without further processing? Or what would be a good `perl` or `awk` one-liner to do the job?

Here is what I currently run

```
qstat -f | awk \
   '/Job Id/ {job=$3 ; 
        if (s > 0) {printf("%6s\t%16s\t%5s\t%8s\n",job,name,state,host); } s+=1} 
   /exec_host/ {host=$3} 
   /Job_Name/ {name=$3} 
   /job_state/ {state = $3} 
   END {printf("%6s\t%16s\t%5s\t%8s\n",job,name,state,host)}
   BEGIN {printf("%6s\t%16s\t%5s\t%8s\n","JobId","Job Name","State","Hosts")}'
```

**UPDATE**

Here is a fragment of `qstat -f` output:

```
Job Id: 29835
    Job_Name = taverna
    Job_Owner = meos@taverna
    interactive = True
    job_state = R
    queue = all
    qtime = Wed Apr 10 12:02:10 2019
    mtime = Wed Apr 10 12:02:10 2019
    ctime = Wed Apr 10 18:02:10 2019
    exec_host = mathserv/40
    Priority = 4294873206
    euser = meos(1006)
    egroup = meos(1000)
    Resource_List.walltime = 06:00:00
    Resource_List.nodect = 1
    Resource_List.ncpus = 40
```

Such blocks are printed for each job running on the cluster.

Here the `exec_host` parameter identifies the node and the number of slots on that node or a least of nodes with respective numbers of slots allocated for a job. The rest of the parameters are selfexplanatory.

The expected output for just this block would be

```
 JobId          Job Name    State      Hosts
 29835           taverna        R   mathserv/40
```

**UPDATE 2**

For anyone interested, updated the original AWK program to fix some errors
and improve formatting. It happens to work well on Torque and PBS managed clusters as well.

```
qstat -f | awk '/Job Id/ {job=$3 ; 
        if (s > 0) {printf(format,lastjob,user,name,state,host)} ;
        lastjob=job ; s+=1} 
   /exec_host/ {host=$3} 
   /Job_Name/ {name=$3} 
   /job_state/ {state = $3} 
   /Job_Owner/ {user=$3; sub("@.*","",user)}
   END {printf(format,lastjob,user,name,state,host)}
   BEGIN {format="%10s\t%10s\t%25s\t%5s\t%8s\n";
          printf(format,"JobId","Owner","Job Name","State","Hosts")}'
```

Comment: Please include `qstat -f` output

Comment: What value in your sample input identifies a `cluster`? What identifies a `node`? [edit] your question to include the expected output given your posted sample input.

Comment: Is that for a cluster running Slurm (as the tag indicates, and `sinfo` in the question), or PBS (for `qstat`)?

Comment: @Keldorn Yes, the cluster is running Slurm, though I am still more used to PBS commands, so I use qstat that comes with SLURM. Could you please undelete your post?

Comment: Ok, I put my answer back. I do not find `qstat` on the Slurm cluster I am using, it may be an extra tool set up by your admins to ease the transition.

Comment: @Keldorn qstat is a part of `slurm-torque`, an optional package from SchedMD that does exactly what the name says. It provides "_Torque/PBS wrappers for transitition from Torque/PBS to Slurm_".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set directly the `squeue` output format for most of it. AFAICT, it does not provide CPU usage for each node separately though:

`squeue -t R --format="%.20i %.20j %.5t %.5C %R"`

Example output:

```
               JOBID                 NAME    ST  CPUS NODELIST(REASON)
            18206767 job_TR1_11_run007188     R     1 node05
            18206768 job_TR2_11_run007188     R     1 node13
            18207078 job_T1_11_run007188_     R     1 node24
            18207079 job_T2_11_run007188_     R     1 node14
            18207080 job_T3_11_run007188_     R     1 node17
```

See `man squeue` or https://slurm.schedmd.com/squeue.html for more details.

Answer (score 3):

If there's nothing to your liking on the `qstat` man page then parse the output, much like you do.

Here it is with Perl

```
qstat -f | perl -wne'
    /Job Id:\s+(.*)/                              && push(@r, [$1])   or 
    /(?:Job_Name|job_state|exec_host)\s+=\s+(.*)/ && push(@{$r[-1]}, $1) 
    }{ 
    printf("%6s\t%16s\t%5s\t%8s\n", ("JobId", "Job Name", "State", "Hosts")
    printf("%6s\t%16s\t%5s\t%8s\n", @$_) for @r'
```

where I copy your output format.  The `}{` syntax marks the beginning of `END` block.

The `Job Id` line starts a new arrayref in our array of results `@r`, with the ID being its first element. Other desired fields are added, in the order of appearance, to the last (so current) arrayref in `@r`.

Comment: Would it make sense to put the format string into a variable?

Comment: @DmitriChubarov Yes, by all means; in a script that's definitely what I'd do.    Here I thought it'd be simpler this way, since it's only these two lines as they stand.  But, you may well want a variable instead, even in a one-shot "one"-liner.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done without an END block since your inputs and outputs are in the same order.  Width of 0 triggers a newline.

```
qstat -f | perl -nle'
   BEGIN { 
       @fields=("Job Id",qw( Job_Name job_state exec_host )); 
       @width{@fields}=(6,20,9,0); 
       $"="|"; $re=qr/^\s*(@fields)\s*[:=]\s*(.*\S)/; 
       printf "%$width{$_}s\t",$_ for @fields; print "";
   } 
   printf "%$width{$1}s\t%s", $2, $width{$1}?"":"\n" if /$re/
'
```